# LEFT OUTER JOINING two tables, recieving error code 1054 when I try to indent it, versus not indenting

Tags: mysql

[image]
The query above works, but not the second one. They are identical, only thing im trying to do is indent them to make it more inline with what I have been taught

Any help would be appreciated

1054: Unknown column "hytte.hyttenr" in "on clause"

I expect to recieve a result from the 3 tables on both of the queries, as I said, the query above works and the one below does not work.

Comment: Indenting is not a thing in sql - correct syntax is. Please publish the queries as text rather than images together with the table definitions.

Comment: Your parenthesis makes outer table `hytte` invisible.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Comment: I will make sure to publish any further queries as text, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

The two queries you show are not identical, even disregarding the indentation. Indentation or any other whitespace doesn't affect SQL syntax.

The second query has a part of its join syntax enclosed in parentheses. This is not a subquery, it's legitimate syntax to use parentheses in joins. But it changes the order of precedence (similar to parentheses in arithmetic).

Because you added parentheses around the join between `eier` and `utleie`, the way the query evaluates the join expression, it can only reference columns from those two tables. It sees the column reference `hytte.hyttenr` and it says, "I don't know about the table `hytte`."

Comment: Okay I did not know it couldn't reference the other columns outside of the parentheses, the mathematical reference was helpful, that makes alot of sense.

With that in mind I made the query work, thank you